# How to resolve Redis write latency when receiving a large volume of data through WebSockets?

Tags: database, websocket, redis, nosql, redis-cluster

I am receiving market data from an exchange through WebSockets, and I am storing the data in Redis. However, when the incoming data rate increases, there is a delay in writing the data to Redis, and it gets backed up by several minutes.

What can I do to resolve this issue and ensure that the data is written to Redis in a timely manner? Should I consider using a different data store or making changes to my Redis configuration?

I am using AWS Redis for my application, and I have tried increasing the server performance and adjusting the cluster configuration, but it did not solve the issue. Even with these changes, there is still a delay in writing data to Redis.